# When to transliterate words in foreign languages?

Tags: united-states, writing-style

I'm writing a philosophy paper relying heavily on Aristotle and discussing several of his primary terms, including their etymologies. Therefore I say words like ἐντελέχεια and θεωρεῖν a lot. Since a fundamental premise of my essay is that we lack straightforward English equivalents for these words, and their etymologies give us important clues to their meanings, I have to leave them untranslated. But untranslated does not necessarily mean written out in an unfamiliar script---I could transliterate these words as *entelekheia* and *theorein*.

Other writers who share my views on translation go both ways on this. For instance Heidegger, in *Basic Concepts of Aristotelian Philosophy*, reproduces Greek script, while Christopher Long, in *The Ethics of Ontology*, transliterates. (Though obviously their audiences are *very* different.) My advisor has not expressed any preference on this matter.

Given this lack of deciding factors, what speaks for, and what speaks against, transliterating all the Greek words I use? Which audiences prefer one over the other? How would the decision to pursue publication (I will almost certainly not pursue this, but I am curious) change things?

Comment: Why not both?  Unless you're publishing in a classics journal you can't assume everyone can read the Greek alphabet.

Comment: @gerrit Here's a sentence from the essay: "Heidegger 2009, §17 considers ἕξις more fully but only as a preliminary step to a discussion of πάθη and ἀρετή." Not a great sentence but I think it would only be worse if it read "considers ἕξις, hexis, more fully but only as a preliminary step to a discussion of πάθη, pathe, and ἀρετή, arete." Your comment prompts a related one, which maybe I should explicitly ask elsewhere: how many US virtue ethicists can read the Greek alphabet? But answers here should be more general, not restricted to this paper.

Comment: I would write "...considers *ἕξις (hexis)* more fully..."

Comment: Greek and transiteration on first use, then transliteration thereafter? For a Philosophy paper not every reader will be sufficiently confident in reading Greek to not be distracted; if it were a Classics paper you could assume they would.

Comment: I've seen Greek with parenthesized transliteration on first use, then Greek only thereafter.

Comment: 1 I believe "entelechy" is an English word, although few people would recognize it. 2 I suggest you transliterate only the first time, using International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA) (i.e. en.te.lé.kʰeː.a and tʰe.ɔː.ré.ɔː ) and not Latin letters that most readers won't know how to sound out; and then continue using Greek letters.